# use rotating information with google distance matrix api with javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix, service, distance

I'm running a loop with an application but I want to assign the data in the row to individual html elements. I'd appreciate it if you could show me what's wrong with the code.

I want to do from a few different points according to a single distance and time to get the information via javascript and show the elements on html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>distancematrixjs</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="sonuc">
    <p id="mesafe1">Mesafe 1:</p>
    <p id="sure1">Süre 1:</p>
    <p id="StatusDurum">Durum:</p>
    
    <input type="button" value="hesapla" onClick="getDistance()"/>
    
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        var origin1 = {lat: 41.67415, lng: 26.56253};
        
        var destinationA = 'İstanbul, Türkiye';
        
                    
         
        
        
    function getDistance()
    {
       
        var service=new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins:[origin1],
            destinations:[destinationA],
            travelMode:'DRIVING',
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
 },function(response,status){
        if(status !=='OK'){
            StatusDurum.innerHTML+='Hata'+status;
        }else{
            StatusDurum.innerHTML+=response;
            
            
        
            
         var outputMesafe1=document.getElementById('mesafe1');
         var outputSure1=document.getElementById('sure1'); 
            
           outputMesafe1.innerHTML+=response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;                 
           outputSure1.innerHTML+=response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text; 
                  
                  
          
            
        }
    }
        
        
        
        
    
    
    
    </script>
    
    
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-APİ-KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Breaking a structure when calling a function.
The Google library uploading specified the function call "callback = initMap" you do not need it. Also, in order for everything to work, you need to get the API KEY from Google and embed it into the library uploading instead of YOUR_API_KEY

```
<script>
var origin1 = {lat: 41.67415, lng: 26.56253};
var destinationA = 'İstanbul, Türkiye';
function getDistance() {
    var service=new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins:[origin1],
            destinations:[destinationA],
            travelMode:'DRIVING',
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        },function(response,status){
            if(status !=='OK'){
                StatusDurum.innerHTML+='Hata'+status;
            }else{
                StatusDurum.innerHTML+=response;
                var outputMesafe1=document.getElementById('mesafe1');
                var outputSure1=document.getElementById('sure1'); 
               outputMesafe1.innerHTML+=response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;                 
               outputSure1.innerHTML+=response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;        
            }
        })
};
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```